# Expressjs asynchronous Settings from Database at Start

Tags: javascript, express, asynchronous

When starting the Express-Application I'd like to load some Settings from a Mongo-Database and make them application-wide available. Since the DB-Request is asonchronous this leads to errors in other places that depend on the setting before they are loaded. Whats the usual approach to make Express wait in its inital load of the app.js for data that is requested from a database?

Comment: This is way too generic. sounds like you want to look into using mongoose. use express routes that fetch mongoose queries...

Comment: I'm using mongoose. And the question is not about how to request data. The Question is about how to make express in the initial load of app.js wait until the settings are retreived from the db.

Comment: Do you have something like `MongoClient.connect()` on your code? What kind of settings are you trying to load? Can't you save them in a file? Maybe show some code can help us.